# DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

I am working on a project which I started building on bootstrap 4.3.1.

I'm crazy about this one Javascript and html coding.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('user.panel') }}">
    User panel
</a>
```

I get this error in console.

> SyntaxError: 'http://localhost:8000/user/panel' is not a valid selector
>
> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'http://localhost:8000/user/panel' is not a valid selector.
>       at Object.getSelectorFromElement (http://localhost:8000/themes/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:1466)
>       at http://localhost:8000/themes/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:46766
>       at Array.map ()
>       at n.t.refresh (http://localhost:8000/themes/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:46740)
>       at new n (http://localhost:8000/themes/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:46381)

I figured out that it occur due to the dropdown because of this error the dropdown does not work. I also checked, that if I am using href="javascript:void(0);", href="#!" the error occur but if i use anchor tag without href or href="#" then it is working fine.

[image: Only god]

**Note:** I need the solution with href="javascript:void(0); as href="# in the address link does not look pretty and page scrolls up to the top .

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    @guest
    <li class="navbar-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">Register/Login<i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-right m-2 position-absolute" style="width:300px;left:-111px;">
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="btn btn-primary d-block m-3">Login</a>
            <span class="m-3">Are you new user?<a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="link-sign">Login</a></span>
        </div>
    </li>
    @else
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                {{ Auth::user()->first_name }}&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->last_name }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('user.panel') }}">
                    User Panel
                </a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="logout-button">
                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                </a>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
    @endguest
</ul>
```

The error comes in the following line.

```
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 50
});
```

script.js

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"; // Start of use strict

    // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
    $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 54)
                }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
    $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });

    // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '#mainNav',
        offset: 50
    });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict

AOS.init({
    easing: 'ease-in-out-sine'
});

$('#logout-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#logout-form').submit();
});


$('#select').change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find(':selected');
    $('#description').html($selected.data('description'));
}).trigger('change');
$("#select").change(function() {
    var color = $(this).val();
    if (color == "laptop_repair") {
        $(".box").not(".laptop_repair").hide();
        $(".laptop_repair").show();
    } else if (color == "install_windows") {
        $(".box").not(".install_windows").hide();
        $(".install_windows").show();
    } else if (color == "backup") {
        $(".box").not(".backup").hide();
        $(".backup").show();
    } else if (color == "antivirus") {
        $(".box").not(".antivirus").hide();
        $(".antivirus").show();
    } else if (color == "magenta") {
        $(".box").not(".magenta").hide();
        $(".magenta").show();
    } else {
        $(".box").hide();
    }
});
getSelectorFromElement: function getSelectorFromElement(element) {
    var selector = element.getAttribute('data-target');

    if (!selector || selector === '#') {
        var hrefAttr = element.getAttribute('href');
        selector = hrefAttr && hrefAttr !== '#' ? hrefAttr.trim() : '';
    }

    return selector && document.querySelector(selector) ? selector : null;
}
```

Comment: Error comes from `themes/js/script.js` on line 24, please add relevant code.

Comment: @skobaljic I update my post. and I need all codes of `script.js`

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from Bootstrap's [scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/) component, that clearly states:

> Anchors () are required and must point to an element with that id.

or

> Navbar links must have resolvable id targets. For example, a `<a
>   href="#home">home</a>` must correspond to something in the DOM like
>   `<div id="home">`.

You have couple of solutions:

1. Change the scrollspy tartget from `#mainNav` to something more narrow which does not include `.navbar-nav`
2. In case you wanna track/spy the links inside the `.navbar-nav`, than you need either to hack scrollspy source, or to use some other component
3. Keep everything as is, but use valid local links in anchors.

Comment: No, because you haven't posted all the relevant code, `#mainNav` element is not inside it.